# is opengl suitable for making simulator of robotic arm or any other would be best for this purpose?

Tags: c#

i m final year student want to make simulator for my robotic arm using opengl as i have command on c sharp so i would do coding using c sharp.
now have a query that would it be better to use opengl for simulator preparation or rather any other software(tool) will be best for the achievement of this task.
DO inform me
i would be grateful to u

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let's get one thing straight: OpenGL is a graphics API. It can help you draw things to the screen, but it will not help you with "simulator preparation" (whatever that means).

If your program needs to display 3D graphics, OpenGL is one way to accomplish this. Direct3D would be another way, if you're on Windows (likely, since you're using C#).

However, both APIs have a learning curve, and it will take you a while to get up to speed with them. If your purpose is to display some simple 3D graphics without having to worry too much about the implementation, it may be better to use some engine or library on top of either OpenGL or Direct3D. I have no experience in this area, but you might want to look for something that allows you to load models from a file, and lets you render them in a few simple statements.

Answer (score 0):

opengl or direct3d are great for rendering the 3Dimensional object, but for the simulation of the robot you should use a framework that offers you a scenegraph and/or a physics engine

have a look at the various gaming engines like ogre, or have a look at the blender game engine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one good [OpenGL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/sharpgl.aspx) library for C#.  Note that graphics is only a small part of what you'll need.  Is your intention to create your own kinematics model or are you planning to use a physics system to articulate the robot based on raw 'servo' commands?  If you want an off-the-shelf physics system, a good one is [NVidia PhysX](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/physx_downloads.html), though you have to explicitly register as a developer with them to get the API and it's in C++ (so you'd have to use C++/CLI To make good use of it.)